# Bedeutung von "hin zu"

Tags: meaning

> Die Entwicklung hin zu einer offenen Gesellschaft
>
> Der Sprung hin zu...

Welche Rolle spielt das Wort "hin" im Satz und was wird dadurch betont?

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "welche Rolle"? "Hin zu" gibt eine Richtung an, als Gegenteil von "weg von"...?

Comment: @IQV The question is not about "hin zu" but about "hin". In other words - what is the difference between "die Entwicklung **hin zu** einer offenen Geselschaft" and "die Entwicklung **zu** einer offenen Gesellschaft"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Funktion des "hin" hier ist eine rhetorische.

Manche Teile der menschlichen Rede tragen keine eigene, separate Bedeutung sondern dienen anderen kommunikativen Zielen, zum Beispiel der Vermittlung einer Emotion des Sprechers.

Im Falle des "hin" im Beispielsatz geht es um die effektvolle Strukturierung der Rede. Inhaltlich und syntaktisch ist das "hin" verzichtbar. Man könnte ohne weiteres auch sagen

> Die Entwicklung zu einer offenen Gesellschaft

Jedoch empfinden viele Nutzer der deutschen Sprache das "zu" hier als zu kurz; man wittert die Gefahr, dass es überhört oder missverstanden wird; man möchte mehr Aufmerksamkeit auf die Richtung der Entwicklung legen; man möchte den ganzen Vorgang betonen; darum fügt man ein Wörtlein hinzu, das diesem Teil des Satzes mehr Gewicht gibt. Dann wird daraus

> Die Entwicklung hin zu einer offenen Gesellschaft

In diesem Satz, wenn er gesprochen wird, trägt das "hin" auch die Betonung, und es ist üblich, danach sogar kurz zu pausieren:

> Die Entwicklung hin (!) ... ... zu einer offenen Gesellschaft.

Dies gibt dem Hörer Zeit, sich auf den Gedanken einzustellen. Außerdem entsteht ein Spannungsbogen: Der Hörer wartet, was nun kommt, und grübelt vielleicht schon mal, was es wohl sein mag.

Comment: Es besteht auch eine Parallelität zum Gegenbegriff "weg von". In jenem Fall ist das Wort "weg" nicht auslassbar, weil "die Entwicklung von alternativen Energien" nicht dasselbe bedeutet wie "die Entwicklung weg von alternativen Energien".

Comment: Dieser Punkt hält Stich!

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem Empfinden beschreibt das *hin zu* einen Schritt auf dem Weg in Richtung eines noch nicht erreichten (mitunter eines gar nicht gänzlich zu erreichenden) Zieles, während ein bloßes *zu* auch den möglicherweise letzten Schritt zur Erreichung des Zieles beschreiben kann.

Beispiele zur Verdeutlichung:

- Das ist ein weiterer Schritt auf dem Weg hin zu unserem Ziel
  vs.
- Das ist der entscheidende Schritt zum Erreichen unseres Zieles

Aber wie gesagt ist das nur meinem Empfinden geschuldet, und in der Praxis wird die Trennung nicht so klar sein.